# No gateway IP for router

Tags: networking, ip, gateway, motorola

I was trying to make my router to act as a repeater but something went wrong and now the problem i am facing is... my router don't have any default gateway ip now...

Here is my current ipconfig,,, without any default gateway ip... Please help to correct this issue...

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Vijay
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-7B-CB-FA-37-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-DD-08-F2-C6-7B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8059 PCI-E Gigabit Ether
net Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 54-42-49-6A-BA-5B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9144:b905:b252:6411%13(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.100.17(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 357843529
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-17-25-87-78-DD-08-F2-C6-7B

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network
Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-DD-08-F2-C6-7B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{13E15DD6-80DE-45D3-8A24-843217C8FD1E}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your device was assigned an APIPA address (from the range 169.254.0.0/16), meaning that it also could not obtain an address via DHCP. If you can figure out how, I would say just try resetting your router.

If you have reset your router, try this follow-on step. Click Start -> Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Manage Wireless Networks (on the left). Highlight the network you're trying to connect to, and click "Adapter Properties". In the window that opens, click on Internet Protocol Version 4, and choose the Properties button. Make sure that the buttons are checked for both "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically".

See if that solves your issue.

Comment: A few follow-up questions. Do you have any other devices connected to this router? Do you remember what the default gateway IP was before you made the change? If so, you could try manually configuring the gateway and DNS server addresses.

Comment: the previous gateway ip was default 192.168.0.1 . and please tell me how to manually configure the gateway and DNS without accessing the routers firmware...???

Comment: Problem solved... did hardware reset by pressing the reset button on modem for about 35 seconds... :)